# Sending data to server in JSONObjectRequest using Volley Library. ERROR

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to pass some values to server using JSONObjectRequest of Volley library. But somehow the data isn't being sent to server and the variable of server side script which is supposed to receive the data is empty.
Here is the JSONObjectRequest code

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
            obj.put("userid", "userid");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                URL_FEED, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                Log.d(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext()),"Response generated");
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("Error - >",error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error is -->> " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

php side to get the variable

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
```

Comment: what is the response code of the request, when its executed fully

Comment: Error - >﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: try to run this on postman, before running from the code, it will help you to find out where the problem is.

Comment: if i try to run the php script without any userid this is what i get. but if i give some values to the userid in my php script, i get proper json feed.. this is without userid ... <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: userid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\socialoid22\tempfeed.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"feed":[]}
... and with userid, given, {"feed":[//values here]}

Comment: Please post the postman response here, or you can provide details , so that i can create a request for you

Comment: @warlock my php script is just perfect there is some issue with this java code but i changed my request method and now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it to work by changing the JSONObjectRequest to StringRequest and then convert the Onresponse String to JSONObject as follow

```
// making fresh volley request and getting json
        StringRequest jsonReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                URL_FEED, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + s.toString());
                JSONObject response = null;
                try {
                    response = new JSONObject(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext()), "Response generated");
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("Error - >",error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error is -->> " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userid", userid);
                return params;

            }
        };
```